# When i perform XSS attack on the form that i created, nothing happena?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a simple form and perform XSS attack on that form.
But when i type `<script>alert("Hello")</script>` on any fields but nothing happens.

No input validation has been added yet though. The function of buttons is working well so far

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <td width="615">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="614" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#333333"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="614" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr bgcolor="#ecece0"></tr>
       
            <tr bgcolor="#333333"></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <font face="Arial">
        <title>BadStore.net - Sign our Guestbook</title>
            <h1>Sign our Guestbook!</h1>
            <hr><p>Please complete this form to sign our Guestbook.  The email field is not required, but helps us contact you to respond to your feedback.  Thanks!</p><p></p><hr>
    <table border="0" celllpadding="10">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td> <td><input type="text" name="email" size="40"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="TOP">Comments:</td> 
                <td><textarea name="comments" cols="60" rows="4"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <hr>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Add Entry">  <input type="reset"></center></font></td>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to ever store comments, or load them. A (stored) XSS attack relies on code being stored on the backend, and loaded and evaluated at a later time on a client's computer. You're never storing or loading anything.

Comment: Oh i see may i know how to stored comments on the backend?

Comment: Look up DVWA (Damn Vulnerable Web App) if you want to practice stuff like this, but don't have quite enough knowledge to write up a vulnerable site to test on.

Comment: To do this, you'd need to manage a database with PHP on the backend, which is a another level of complexity if you don't know SQL.

Comment: Alright thank you so much